# Adding Dynamic HTML to Facebook's Fan Page

Tags: facebook

I am trying to add a new box on the main view of our Fan Page.

And populate it with HTML from our main webserver (django) when the user opens the fan-page.

Is there any way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

You should read up on creating [facebook applications](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/canvas/)...
Once you have an application you can setup a [page tab application](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/appsonfacebook/pagetabs/) and add that to your fan page.
Finally go to your fan page settings, and the "Manage Permissions" tab.  There you can set your "Default landing tab".  Be aware, as the administrator of the page the landing tab will not work for YOUR account - you'll have to log into a different facebook account to see this behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

There's two way of reading what you want to do : 
1/ You want a landing for non-fans
2/ You want a landing page for all your user

The first one is achievable by creating an application and fill the page tabs fields (PAge tab name, Page tab url, secure page tab url). Then going to the App Profile Page, add it to your page. Then on the admin panel of your page pick your app as default landing tab.

The second isn't achievable. One a user likes your page, its default page is your wall and you can't change it.

I'm not sure exactly what you wants to achieve, hope I helped.